# Using open() with Command Line Argument in Python

Tags: python, arguments, argparse

I know I'm missing something obvious.  I'm using argparse to parse two input files. I get the expected output from the main function when I print the variables 'file1' and 'file2'

However I attempt to use 'file1' and 'file2' in sub functions. I also attempt to print out the new variables(which fail). What I am trying to to is set the command line arguments to variables and then use those variables later in the code.

```
"""
Created on Fri Oct 21 12:02:34 2016

@author: jsklein
"""
import pandas as pd
import csv
import argparse

# Parse command line arguments and set them to variables to be used later
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Compares Two CSV files for matches and differences indexed on a column')

    parser.add_argument("-i", help="Name of first CSV import file", action="store", dest="infile1", required="yes")
    parser.add_argument("-I", help="Name of second CSV import file", action="store", dest="infile2", required="yes")

    args = parser.parse_args()    
    file1 = args.infile1
    file2 = args.infile2
    print(file1)
    print(file2)
# Define Compare funtion that joins on specified column

    def merge_csvs():
        a = pd.read_csv(file1)
        b = pd.read_csv(file2)
        print(a)
        print(b)

        merged = b.merge(a, on='SWREV')
        merged.to_csv("merged_results.csv", index=False) 

 # Define Diff function that diffs on specified column

    def diff_csvs():
        s = open(file1, 'r')
        k = open(file2, 'r')
        print(s)
        print(k)

        checkS = csv.reader(s)
        checkK = csv.reader(k)

        output1 =  [row for row in checkS if row not in checkK]
        output2 =  [row for row in checkK if row not in checkS]

        with open("A_notin_B.csv", "w") as f:
            writer = csv.writer(f)
            writer.writerows(output1)

        with open("B_notin_A.csv", "w") as l:
            writer = csv.writer(l)
            writer.writerows(output2)

# Main Function that Calls all the other functions


main()
```

Here is an example of running the code, notice that the other variables 'a', 'b', 's', and 'k' do not print(And yes I'm expecting a lot of output:

```
$ python csv_compare.py -i csv1.csv -I csv2.csv
csv1.csv
csv2.csv
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve] including how you're calling this and what happens when you do.

Comment: Added edits. Thank You.

Comment: you doesn't execute `merge_csvs()` and `diff_csvs()` so it can't print.

Comment: Why were you expecting anything else? You never actually call the functions you define.

Comment: Thanks I got rid of the arg_parser definition and called the parsed argumets as global variables then I modified main() so that both functions were called and we have woirking code. Thanks! I knew I was missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but maybe this helps (if this is what you are trying to do):

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
import argparse

# Parse command line arguments and set them to variables to be used later
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Compares Two CSV files for matches and differences indexed on a column')

    parser.add_argument("-i", help="Name of first CSV import file", action="store", dest="infile1", required="yes")
    parser.add_argument("-I", help="Name of second CSV import file", action="store", dest="infile2", required="yes")

    args = parser.parse_args()    
    file1 = args.infile1
    file2 = args.infile2
    print(file1)
    print(file2)

    # explicitly call the other functions
    merge_csvs(file1,file2)
    diff_csvs(file1,file2)

# Define Compare funtion that joins on specified column
def merge_csvs(file1,file2):
    a = pd.read_csv(file1)
    b = pd.read_csv(file2)
    print(a)
    print(b)

    merged = b.merge(a, on='SWREV')
    merged.to_csv("merged_results.csv", index=False) 

# Define Diff function that diffs on specified column
def diff_csvs(file1,file2):
    s = open(file1, 'r')
    k = open(file2, 'r')
    print(s)
    print(k)

    checkS = csv.reader(s)
    checkK = csv.reader(k)

    output1 =  [row for row in checkS if row not in checkK]
    output2 =  [row for row in checkK if row not in checkS]

    with open("A_notin_B.csv", "w") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(output1)

    with open("B_notin_A.csv", "w") as l:
        writer = csv.writer(l)
        writer.writerows(output2)

# Main Function that Calls all the other functions
main()
```

Basically what I did was:

- Define your functions outside the main() method
- Add file1 and file2 as parameters
- call the two functions from main(), providing file1 and file2 as parameters for each call

The code posted above is untested. I just edited your code

Comment: Yes this works. I wasn't calling explicit calling the other functions. I also have a version of the code below that removes the agrs_parser() and sets global parsed variables for use in the merge_csvs() and diff_csvs() later on in the code

Answer (score 0):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Fri Oct 21 12:02:34 2016

@author: jsklein
"""
import pandas as pd
import csv
import argparse

# Parse command line arguments and set them to variables to be used later
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Compares Two CSV files for       matches and differences indexed on a column')

parser.add_argument("-i", help="Name of first CSV import file", action="store", dest="infile1", required="yes")
parser.add_argument("-I", help="Name of second CSV import file", action="store", dest="infile2", required="yes")

args = parser.parse_args()    
file1 = args.infile1
file2 = args.infile2
print(file1)
print(file2)

# Define Compare funtion that joins on specified column

def merge_csvs():
    a = pd.read_csv(file1)
    b = pd.read_csv(file2)
    print(a)
    print(b)
    merged = b.merge(a, on='SWREV')
    merged.to_csv("merged_results.csv", index=False) 

# Define Diff fuction that diffs on specified column

def diff_csvs():

    s = open(file1, 'r')
    k = open(file2, 'r')
    print(s)
    print(k)
    checkS = csv.reader(s)
    checkK = csv.reader(k)

    output1 =  [row for row in checkS if row not in checkK]
    output2 =  [row for row in checkK if row not in checkS]

    with open("A_notin_B.csv", "w") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(output1)

    with open("B_notin_A.csv", "w") as l:
        writer = csv.writer(l)
        writer.writerows(output2)

# Main Function that Calls all the other functions
def main():
    merge_csvs()
    diff_csvs()

main()
```

So I got rid of the arg_parser function which mad the global vars available to the other functions